# What will "Efavirenz amino alcohol methyl carbamate" look like?

Tags: molecular-structure

I'm translating a text in which a possible derivative (produced by harsh conditions) of this drug is mentioned:

[image]

Its name is put as "Efavirenz amino alcohol methyl carbamate".

I wonder what it will look like.

The carbamate group, according to Wikipedia, will look like this:

[image]

And there will also be an alcohol (hydoxyl) group and an amino group somewhere. Will there be two nitrogens, or will the only nitrogen atom particiape both in the "amino group" described in the name and in the "methyl carbamate"?

Comment: Maybe the lactone on the right is hydrolyzed to the acid and alcohol, and then the acid group forms a methyl ester.

Comment: @f'' - thank you, I'll try to understand it. I can see an acid forming there, but have not enough imagination to imagine where the hydroxyl will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "efavirenz amino alcohol methyl carbamate" is (S)-methyl 4-chloro-2-(4-cyclopropyl-1,1,1-trifluoro-2-hydroxybut-3-yn-2-yl)phenyl carbamate (CAS 211563-41-6),
[image: efavirenz amino alcohol methyl carbamate]

according to this [reference](http://www.mangalamdrugs.com/impurities.html).